# One of my Pine editor scripts doesn't seem to make trades

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm backtesting trade strategies on tradingview, and am using the pine editor to program them (with help from examples and youtube videos).
So far I've made several ones that work in terms of correct entries and exits etc.
Every time I get one in order I try to make it a bit more complex.

The last one I'm working on doesn't seem to do anything.
There are no trades in the "Strategy Tester" screen at all.
I've gone through the code over and over again but I can't find out why.

Here's what I find strange:

1. I've got some plots on the end for the "Trade Stop Price" and "Trade Target Price" and those plot every time I've got a correct setup for entry. So it does recognize the entries.
2. I didn't change the strategy.entry or strategy.exit parts, which I took over from the previous strategy which did work

Hopefully someone can help me?
Thank you in advance!

(Also, if you see anything that makes you go "wow, that's dumb", feel free to comment)

Corove

```
// Previously 3 or more strong HA candles in same direction
// Closed last HA with body between 40 and 60 percent of wick


//@version=4
strategy("Heikin Ashi Indecisive after strong move", overlay = true, initial_capital = 1000, default_qty_value = 2, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)

// input from user
stopMultiplier = input(title="Stop Loss ATR", type=input.float, defval=1.0, tooltip="Stop loss multiplier (x ATR)")
rr = input(title="Risk:Reward", type=input.float, defval=1.0, step=0.5, tooltip="Risk:Reward profile")

// defined variables
start = timestamp(2021, 10, 28, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2021, 11, 28, 0, 0)
symbol = syminfo.tickerid
period = "5"
lookback = 2

// calculate atr
atr = atr(14)

// get Heikin Ashi values
heikinashiOpen = security(heikinashi(symbol), period, open)
heikinashiClose = security(heikinashi(symbol), period, close)
heikinashiHigh = security(heikinashi(symbol), period, high)
heikinashiLow = security(heikinashi(symbol), period, low)

// define a green (rising) and red (falling) Heikin Ashi candle
rising = heikinashiClose > heikinashiOpen
falling = heikinashiClose < heikinashiOpen

// calculate candle- wick- and bodysizes
candleSize = heikinashiHigh - heikinashiLow
bodySize = heikinashiOpen > heikinashiClose ? heikinashiOpen - heikinashiClose : heikinashiClose - heikinashiOpen
upperWick = heikinashiOpen > heikinashiClose ? heikinashiHigh - heikinashiOpen : heikinashiHigh - heikinashiClose
lowerWick = heikinashiOpen > heikinashiClose ? heikinashiClose - heikinashiLow : heikinashiOpen - heikinashiLow

// define a Heikin Ashi with hard push in one direction
hardRise = rising and (heikinashiLow == heikinashiOpen)
hardFall = falling and (heikinashiHigh == heikinashiOpen)

// define HA end of move candle
indecisiveCandle = upperWick > candleSize * 0.35 and lowerWick > candleSize * 0.35

// determine if we have a valid setup
switchLongComing = (indecisiveCandle or rising) and hardFall[1] and hardFall[2] and hardFall[3] and not na(atr)
switchShortComing = (indecisiveCandle or falling) and hardRise[1] and hardRise[2] and hardRise[3] and not na(atr)

// check if we have confirmation for a trade
validLong = switchLongComing and strategy.position_size == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed
validShort = switchShortComing and strategy.position_size == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed

// calculate stops and targets
stopSize = atr * stopMultiplier
lowestLow = lowest(low, lookback)
longStopPrice = lowestLow - stopSize
longStopDistance = close - longStopPrice
longTargetPrice = close + (longStopDistance * rr)
highestHigh = highest(high, lookback)
shortStopPrice = highestHigh + stopSize
shortStopDistance = shortStopPrice - close
shortTargetPrice = close - (longStopDistance * rr)

// save stops and targets for trade
var tradeStopPrice = 0.0
var tradeTargetPrice = 0.0
if validLong
    tradeStopPrice := longStopPrice
    tradeTargetPrice := longTargetPrice
if validShort
    tradeStopPrice := shortStopPrice
    tradeTargetPrice := shortTargetPrice

// enter trades when a valid entry is found
if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long, when=validLong)
    strategy.entry(id="Short", long=strategy.short, when=validShort)

// exit trades whenever a stop or target is hit
strategy.exit("Long Exit", from_entry = "Long", limit = tradeTargetPrice, stop = tradeStopPrice, when = strategy.position_size > 0)
strategy.exit("Short Exit", from_entry = "Short", limit = tradeTargetPrice, stop = tradeStopPrice, when = strategy.position_size < 0)

// graphical information
plot(strategy.position_size != 0 or validLong or validShort ? tradeStopPrice : na, title = "Trade Stop Price", color = color.red, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(strategy.position_size != 0 or validLong or validShort ? tradeTargetPrice : na, title = "Trade Target Price", color = color.green, style = plot.style_linebr)
inLongTrade = strategy.position_size > 0
inShortTrade = strategy.position_size < 0
notInTrade = strategy.position_size == 0
bgcolor(notInTrade == false ? inLongTrade ? color.green : color.red : color.white)
```

EDIT:
After some more testing I found out that this problem of not opening positions happens on some charts and not on others.
The script will take trades on forex pairs for example, but not on most futures or stocks.
Still no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if validLong
    tradeStopPrice := longStopPrice
    tradeTargetPrice := longTargetPrice
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long)


if validShort
    tradeStopPrice := shortStopPrice
    tradeTargetPrice := shortTargetPrice
    strategy.entry(id="Short", short=strategy.short)
```

And um... I am seeing you missed changing 'long' to 'short' in part of your entry logic; "**long=strategy.short**"

```
if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long, when=validLong)
    strategy.entry(id="Short", long=strategy.short, when=validShort)
```

Let me know if this helps. I've only given a quick skim over your code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering!

I tried your solution but I first got an error that the "short" label wasn't recognized.
I think the long in "long=strategy.short" is a boolean to check the direction of the entry, so more like long=true or long=false.

Changing it back to long=strategy.short in the "Try:" part of your post gave the same result that I got before.

Regards,
Corove